# UserDict is not considered as a dict by unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
import unittest
from UserDict import UserDict

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, x):
        UserDict.__init__(self, x=x)

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dict(self):
        m = MyDict(42)
        assert {'x': 42} == m # this passes
        self.assertDictEqual({'x': 42}, m) # failure at here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I got

```
AssertionError: Second argument is not a dictionary
```

Should I use the built-in `dict` as the base class, instead of `UserDict`?

Comment: Probably? What is `UserDict`? Where does it come from (and [why does the module have capital letters in its name?](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names))?

Comment: @HenryKeiter see https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html

Comment: You can always cast `m` to dict: `dict(m)` or use `m.data` instead of `m`.

Comment: @alecxe Eww... Never knew about that. I guess the asker should be testing `m.data` then?

Comment: Firstly, consider whether you really need your own dict class, its very rare that you do. Secondly, just inherit from `dict`, I don't know any reason to inherit from UserDict instead. (It was neccessary in very old versions of python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [`assertDictEqual()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictEqual) first checks that both arguments are `dict` instances:

```
def assertDictEqual(self, d1, d2, msg=None):
    self.assertIsInstance(d1, dict, 'First argument is not a dictionary')
    self.assertIsInstance(d2, dict, 'Second argument is not a dictionary')
    ...
```

And, `UserDict` is not an instance of `dict`:

```
>>> m = UserDict(x=42)
>>> m
{'x': 42}
>>> isinstance(m, dict)
False
```

Instead of using `UserDict` class directly, use the `data` property, which contains a real dictionary:

```
self.assertDictEqual({'x': 42}, m.data)
```

Or, as others already suggested, just use a regular dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `UserDict` is not actually a `dict` object, because it was created long ago when you couldn't inherit from the built-in `dict` type. According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html):

> [UserDict] has been largely supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from `dict`...

So I'd probably just inherit from `dict` and be done with it; I don't see any functionality that `UserDict` provides over that option.

---

Note that I also take issue personally with `UserDict`<sup>*</sup>, because the module name [violates PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), and that's annoying.

---

<sup>*</sup>Which I didn't know existed until eight minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

From Python `unittest` source

```py
def assertDictEqual(self, d1, d2, msg=None):
    self.assertIsInstance(d1, dict, 'First argument is not a dictionary')
    self.assertIsInstance(d2, dict, 'Second argument is not a dictionary')
```

These two arguments must be instance of `dict`.

And unfortunately `UserDict` instance is not instance of `dict`

```py
assert isinstance(m, dict) # this is False
```

As the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserDict says, you can use `m.data` to return a real `dict`.

> `IterableUserDict.data`
>
> ```
> A real dictionary used to store the contents of the UserDict class.
> ```